# Send id from select option to ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a List of my projects That each project has id. Now I Want send id when click in each project select options, But Just first project id typed. My code is here:

```
<input type="hidden" id="project_id" value="{{$project->id}}">
<select id="Ouritem" class="form-control">                                                                                            
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="1"finish</option>
    <option value="2">wait</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#Ouritem', function (event) {
        var project_id = $('#project_id').val();
        console.log(project_id);
    });
)};
</script>
```

How I Can fix it, that when clicked project's select option receive this project_id?

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the input, not the selectbox.

```
var project_id = $('#project_id').val();
```

should be

```
var project_id = $('#Ouritem').val();
```

Comment: this code give me value of option I need to project_id in hidden input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value of selected option when it changes , use this :

```
$('#Ouritem').on('change', function(){
    var project_id = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: this code give me value of option I need to project_id in hidden input

Comment: So what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Ouritem').change(function(){ 
    console.log($(#project_id).val());  
});
```

use on change instead of on click